# CRITICAL App Unable to get a Window, abort

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

I want to run my program(kivy), but I get this error:

```
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.     
  File "C:\Users\view\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "C:\Users\view\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, 
in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: OS=windows 10,,,,